# Getting 500 Server Error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to create options for my next wordpress theme but in this theme i use option tree plugin almost 80% options are css so i created a `style.php` file and add it in header like other css files.

but i'm getting 500 server error and if i run file directly i get this error with 500 server error :

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document
>   or in the transfer protocol.

Code of my style.php file :

```
<?php ob_start();
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    include("../../../wp-load.php");
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
?>
<?php
    if(function_exists('ot_get_option')){
?>
body{
    <?php 
        $option = ot_get_option('website_width'); 
        if(isset($option[0]) && isset($option[1])){
            echo "width:".$option[0].$option[1];
        }
    ?>;
}

.span8{
    <?php 
        $option = ot_get_option('width_with_sidebar'); 
        if(isset($option[0]) && isset($option[1])){
            echo "width:".$option[0].$option[1];
        }
    ?>;
}

.span6{
    <?php 
        $option = ot_get_option('content_width_with_two_sidebar'); 
        if(isset($option[0]) && isset($option[1])){
            echo "width:".$option[0].$option[1];
        }
    ?>;
}

.span12{
    <?php 
        $option = ot_get_option('content_width_for_full_width'); 
        if(isset($option[0]) && isset($option[1])){
            echo "width:".$option[0].$option[1];
        }
    ?>;
}

.span6,.span8,.span12{
    <?php 
        $option = ot_get_option('content_margins'); 
        if(isset($option[0]) && isset($option[1])){
            echo "margin:".$option[0].$option[1];
        }
    ?>;
    <?php 
        $option = ot_get_option('content_padding'); 
        if(isset($option[0]) && isset($option[1])){
            echo "padding:".$option[0].$option[1];
        }
    ?>;
}

body{
    <?php
        $option = ot_get_option('style');
        if(isset($option)){
            if($option=='full_width'){
                echo "width:100% !important";
            }
        }
    ?>;
}

#site-title{
    <?php
        $option = ot_get_option('site_title')
        if(isset($option)){
            if(isset($option['font-color'])){
                echo "color:".$option['font-color'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['font-family'])){
                echo "font-family:".$option['font-family'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['font-size'])){
                echo "font-size:".$option['font-size'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['font-variant'])){
                echo "font-variant:".$option['font-variant'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['font-weight'])){
                echo "font-weight:".$option['font-weight'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['letter-spacing'])){
                echo "letter-spacing:".$option['letter-spacing'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['line-height'])){
                echo "line-height:".$option['line-height'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['text-decoration'])){
                echo "text-decoration:".$option['text-decoration'].";";
            }
            if(isset($option['text-transform'])){
                echo "text-transform:".$option['text-transform'].";";
            }
        }
    ?>
}
<?php
    }
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
?>
```

Comment: I doubt a char encoding warning would be the cause of a 500 error. have you looked to see what's showing up in the webserver's error log?

Comment: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://wptesting.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/standard/style.php"

style.php

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: yeesh. wp throwing a 500 because of a lack of encoding? I guess the WP coders would nuke a city because a closet in one apartment has a couple flies.

Comment: @marc is there any fix for it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own answer 
I've syntax error in code but not showing in browser just show 500 internal server error

When i change

```
 $option = ot_get_option('site_title')
```

to

```
 $option = ot_get_option('site_title');
```

it works perfect